# Remove space above table

Tags: tables, tabularx, tcolorbox

I created a table like this:

```
{\bf \color{LightBlue} \small repding} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt ,colback=ColWhite, colframe = ColWhite]
        \begin{table}[H]
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
                     \textcolor{GrayMid}{Code} & \textcolor{GrayMid}{Description} \\ 
                    [0.3ex]
                    \hline
             \hyperref[fac68b5b180]{RA X} & RA\_O \\ \hline 
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

But I get an empty line between the heading and the table. Can someone tell me how to get rid of it?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why are you squeezing a float in `tcolorbox`? And the space has its origin in `tcolorbox`'s setting of space above and below of the box, most likely. Also don't use `\bf` and ... `tcolorbox` has its own way of using `tabularx` ... and please post compilable documents, not just fragments

Comment: Just use the optional title argument of the `tcolorbox` environment to set the title, like `\begin{tcolorbox}[title=repding]' .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `title={...}` etc. options and say `top=0pt`, for example.

`frame hidden` is most times better than `colframe=white`, especially if the background colour isn't white.

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\colorlet{ColWhite}{white}
\colorlet{GrayMid}{black!50}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, sharp corners, frame hidden,colback=ColWhite,fonttitle={\bfseries\small}, coltitle={LightBlue}, title={repding},top=0pt]
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
    \textcolor{GrayMid}{Code} & \textcolor{GrayMid}{Description} \\ 
    [0.3ex]
    \hline
    \hyperref[fac68b5b180]{RA X} & RA\_O \\ \hline 
  \end{tabularx}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

**Using tabularx= option**, which can be used directly in the options, so `tcolorbox` wraps smoothly around the `tabularx` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames,table}{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\colorlet{ColWhite}{white}
\colorlet{GrayMid}{black!50}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, sharp corners,frame hidden,colback=ColWhite,fonttitle={\bfseries\small}, coltitle={LightBlue}, lefttitle={0pt}, title={repding},top=0pt, tabularx={cX}]
    \textcolor{GrayMid}{Code} & \textcolor{GrayMid}{Description} \\ 
    [0.3ex]
    \hline
    \hyperref[fac68b5b180]{RA X} & RA\_O \\ \hline 
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The hyperref link does not work here, of course, since I there is no label for that so far

Comment: @ehmunnehm: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: To the unknown downvoter: Why the downvote? What is wrong with it?